# Use value from previous select in ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
<label class="item item-input item-select" name="coffeehouse">
  <span class="input-label">Coffee House</span>
  <select ng-options="shop.label for shop in products" ng-model="order.coffeehouse"></select>
</label>
<label class="item item-input item-select" name="product">
  <span class="input-label">Product</span>
  <select ng-options="product.label for product in //PROBLEM//" ng-model="order.product"></select>
</label>
```

What I need to do for the second select is get a list of products from `$scope.products[order.coffeehouse].products`, so it depends on the result of the first selection. However, I can't find any documentation on using a scope variable as a key to another scope variable within `ng-options`.

Controller:

```
.controller('DropCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, Products) {
  $ionicLoading.show({
    template: 'Loading...'
  });
  Products.all(function(products) {
    $scope.products = products;
    $ionicLoading.hide();
  });
})
```

Note that it uses a factory, so you won't see the data source here but it's an array of objects like below:

```
[
  { label: 'Store 1', products: [{ label: 'Product 1' }, { label: 'Product 2' }] },
  { label: 'Store 2', products: [{ label: 'Product 1' }, { label: 'Product 2' }] }
]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your controller?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/4te4x93h/1/

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic']);

myApp.controller('DropCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading) {
    $ionicLoading.show({
        template: 'Loading...',
        animation: 'fade-in',
        showBackdrop: true,
        showDelay: 10
    });
    $scope.order = {};
    $scope.products = [
      { label: 'Store 1', products: [{ label: 'Product 1' }, { label: 'Product 2' }] },
      { label: 'Store 2', products: [{ label: 'Product 1' }, { label: 'Product 2' }] }
    ];
    // Mock loading for 1.5 seconds.
    setTimeout(function() {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    }, 1500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.6/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.6/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="DropCtrl">
    <label class="item item-input item-select" name="coffeehouse">
        <span class="input-label">Coffee House</span>
        <select ng-options="shop.label for shop in products" ng-model="order.coffeehouse"></select>
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input item-select" name="product">
        <span class="input-label">Product</span>
        <select ng-options="product.label for product in order.coffeehouse.products" ng-model="order.product"></select>
    </label>
    <p ng-bind="order.coffeehouse.label"></p>
    <p ng-bind="order.product.label"></p>
</div>
```

Where you have `//problem//` you just need to reference your order object's coffeehouse property.

Until you make a selection in the first drop down there will be no options in the second. Once you bind a coffeehouse to the order the second drop down's options will populate.